# Change Texture2D format in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a `Textured2D` loaded which is represented in `ETC_RGB4` how can I change this to another format? say `RGBA32`. Basically I want to switch from 3 channels to 4 and from 4 bit per channel to 8 per channel.

Thanks

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetRawTextureData.html) `GetRawTextureData` returns a byte array, and not `ETC_RBG4` as mentioned. Is there something that I don't understand here?

Comment: It is unclear and confused, let me change my question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can change texture format during run-time.

**1**.Create new empty `Texture2D` and provide `RGBA32` to the `TextureFormat` argument. This will create an empty texture with the `RGBA32` format.

**2**.Use `Texture2D.GetPixels` to obtain the pixels of the old texture that's in `ETC_RGB4` format then use `Texture2D.SetPixels` to put those pixels in the newly created Texture from *#1*.

**3**.Call `Texture2D.Apply` to apply the changes. That's it.

A simple extension method for this:

```
public static class TextureHelperClass
{
    public static Texture2D ChangeFormat(this Texture2D oldTexture, TextureFormat newFormat)
    {
        //Create new empty Texture
        Texture2D newTex = new Texture2D(2, 2, newFormat, false);
        //Copy old texture pixels into new one
        newTex.SetPixels(oldTexture.GetPixels());
        //Apply
        newTex.Apply();

        return newTex;
    }
}
```

**USAGE**:

```
public Texture2D theOldTextue;

// Update is called once per frame
void Start()
{
    Texture2D RGBA32Texture = theOldTextue.ChangeFormat(TextureFormat.RGBA32);
}
```